# Python Negative Indexing differences

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python 3.6, pandas 24.2 and came across a difference.

```
>>> x = pd.Series(range(3))
>>> x[-1]

>>> x = pd.Series(range(3), index=[0,1,2])
>>> x[-1]
```

both produce an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/conda3/ml4t/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 868, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/opt/conda3/ml4t/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 4375, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 81, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 89, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 987, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 993, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: -1
```

while

```
>>> x = pd.Series(range(3), index=['a','b','c'])
>>> x[-1]
2
```

is fine along with any other form of index. They are the same data structure but adding certain types of an index allows negative indexing while others don't?

Comment: Not really. It is the same data structure. Just the index type makes a difference. Why?

Comment: The issue with integer indices is that this is possible with a series: `x = pd.Series(range(3), index=[1,-1,2])`  What should `x[-1]` return here?

Comment: @AMC No, they're aware that that doesn't work, the question is why does it not work for a "normal" series or with the given integer indices, but works for the char indices

Comment: Thank you Nick for clarifying. Indexing with Date also allows [-1].

Comment: @MarkMeyer, it's more of a consistency issue. Why can't slicing just work 100% position based like numpy and use .loc as needed. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data seems to indicate that it's based on numpy too.

Answer (score 1):

For using a negative index, you can use:

```
x.iloc[-1]
```

This would work in all the cases.

Yes, the error is due to consistency issue as mentioned by @a-arnold.

*Since indexing with `[]` must handle a lot of cases, we can't use such index always.*

And when you set a custom index as string, the negative index works as it does not conflict with the integer index.

The [Indexing and selecting data — pandas 1.0.3 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) gives pretty good idea about indexing and selection in pandas.