# Index values in Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series

Consider the following code:

```
my_series = pd.Series(np.arange(3))

my_series[-1]
```

The above code snippet generates a `Key Error`, when trying to retrieve a value.

However, when we specify a custom index while creating the pandas series, the desired output is generated. Like the code below:

```
my_series2 = pd.Series(np.arange(3), index = ['a', 'b', 'c']) 

my_series2[-1]
```

I would like to understand why is there a subtle discrepancy involved between the two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that when you are using the default indexing, calling `my_series[-1]` is just trying to look for index *value* `-1`, which does not exist, hence the `KeyError`. If you had instead sliced, e.g. `my_series[1:-1]`, pandas would have interpreted it as looking for the indices like a normal list and be fine.

Once you change the indexing to the letters, pandas sees a single index as either an index value, if you had used a string, or a positional value when you use a number.

In general, it is recommended to use `.iloc` when you want to use numeric indexing (i.e. positional indexing) and `.loc` when you want to use non-numeric indexing. When using the default indexing, stick to `.iloc` if you want to see the typical python functionality since `.loc` is *inclusive* of the last value when slicing (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-endpoints-are-inclusive) for an explanation why).

---

Also, the same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61435459/python-negative-indexing-differences), but there is no accepted answer. They say that it is an inconsistency, partly because when using just `[]` it is hard to tell if you want the index value or the positional value. That's why it is best to use `.iloc` and `.loc` so your intentions are clear.

Comment: I am aware of `iloc` and `loc` but was curious to know how and why the error arises in that specific case. Thank you for clearing some things out for me :) @jared

Answer (score 0):

The first case. When you create Series you use RangeIndex. RangeIndex don't have reverse indexes, only monotonic integer range.
The second case you use Index (a, b, c). And  you will get a lot of methods and opportunities and you cans use reverse indexes.
You can read more here:
[RangeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.RangeIndex.html?highlight=rangeindex#pandas.RangeIndex)
[Index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.html)